# Can I apply styles to a subset of the text in a user input with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Let's say in a TextInput element, I want to make a word green if it's formatted as @someonesusername the moment they finish writing the word (as opposed to after the text is submitted, in which case it's trivial to send the text to a normal Text component with subset styling. I thought of underlaying a Text component with absolute positioning and making the actual TextInput component invisible, but that seems it might be a headache to keep in sync, and cause usability challenges in the sense that the editing cursor wouldn't be there unless you wired together a custom cursor element to render and that'd be quite the headache for such a small thing I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this the hack I came up with (Amazing question).
React native `TextInput` can take children as input. So why not split the value and add `Text` as children in the `TextInput` and add style the way you want to.
May be wondering how do get the text back? Well these children become string when comes to `onChangeText` callback and get a string back in your state.
For example:

```
// split the text like
const [firstPart, secondPart] = this.state.text.split("@");
const [higlighted , restText] = secondPart ? secondPart.split(' ') : [];
```

Then use them

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
    <Text>{firstPart}</Text>
    {higlighted && <Text style={{
      color: 'blue'
    }}>@{higlighted}</Text>}
    {restText !== undefined && <Text> {restText}</Text>}
  </Text>
</TextInput>
```

Umm, I accept this might be worse solution ever but this works :P

Full example:
https://snack.expo.io/@subkundu/react-native-styles-to-a-subset-of-the-text

[image]